# How to place the same shape multiple times in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7, orchard-modules

How to place the same shape at multiple places. 
E.g. if I do bellow

```
  <Place Parts_FBLikeButton="Content:before"/>
  <Place Parts_FBLikeButton="Content:after"/>
```

Only one get activated (after one) but not both. How can I do this without repeating the shape with a different name.

Comment: This is something that we could probably think about implementing. Would you care opening an issue for requesting this feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You'd need the driver to give you two copies of the shape, with different names. The only thing you can do in order to render the same shape in two different places is call `Display` on the same shape from two different templates. For that, you need to get a reference to the shape, but that's fairly straightforward.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I need to show the number of comments in two places, one before comments, second close to title

Comment: Did you try what has been suggested in both answers?

Comment: finally I accessed directly to the data and wrote it with razor

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to display you shape in main content zone, that you do like this:

First. change Placement.info

```
<Place Parts_FBLikeButton="FBLikeButtonZone:1"/>
```

Second. Partially change (add alternate) content item shape (e.g. Content.cshtml or Content-BlogPost.Detail.cshtml)
from

```
@Display(Model.Content)
```

to

```
@Display(Model.FBLikeButtonZone)
@Display(Model.Content)
@Display(Model.FBLikeButtonZone)
```